# Xcode 6.1. Uncheck and check back portrait orientation. Simulator never appears in portrait mode

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-simulator, xcode6.1

As we know "General" tab has "Device orientation" section where we can specify required device orientations.

The issue is next: when I once uncheck portrait orientation in Xcode settings, the simulator every time works in landscape mode, even if I checked portrait orientation back and reset all settings on the simulator.

Here is a video how it works: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gWDametoyks

Comment: Rotate your iPhone to portrait mode then check. Also disable landscape mode and run. It's not a bug.

Comment: @MidhunMP you can watch my video. even in case you rotate simulator back and check portrait the simulator still appears in landscape mode. I mean by the default it should starts in that mode that was in the previous time (e.g portrait) and if the the Info.plist has portrait orientation then it should appears in portrait, but it does not.

Comment: Where you rotated the simulator ? I'm not seeing that. I mean you need to rotate simulator once the app is in Landscape mode.

"Never Appears" not correct. Quit the simulator and check. Also your app supports landscape mode, so that's not an undesired output. (If your app only supports portrait mode then it's a bug, but in this case it's not)

Comment: Also there is no need to do the portrait untick to get that behavior. Run the app->Rotate to landscape->Now if you run it again, it'll start in landscape mode

Comment: oh, sorry I forget to recorded that part let me re upload this video

Comment: @MidhunMP this is new [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gWDametoyks) that show that simulator works only in landscape mode, even in case rotate back it and rerun with available portrait orientation.

Comment: @MidhunMP seems I can solve this issue if i remove landscape checkmarks and set them back after re run application (as you suggested). But sounds like workaround. Is not it? )

Comment: Yes, it's a weird behavior. Also I checked it by quitting the simulator, not worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the simulator wants to run in landscape is most likely because of your "info.plist" file. The "supported interface orientations" array in the plist contains all of your supported interface orientations. Whichever orientation is first in that array is the one your simulator will default to when you run your application. Unchecking and rechecking an orientation (in the "General" tab) puts it at the bottom of the array, so the simulator doesn't use that orientation. It's an Xcode problem, not a simulator problem, which is why resetting the simulator didn't do anything. If you uncheck landscape and portrait, recheck portrait, then recheck landscape, the simulator will use portrait orientation. Hope it helps :)

Comment: hm, you are right. @MidhanMP suggested the same and it worked as well. But your thoughts about the plist and array totally right. But I have never think about it. I just though that the behavior depends on the simulator settings not on plist. As I remember previous Xcode (e.g. 5 or 4) worked correct. But in any case the answer is connected to the sequence of orientations and I agree with you. But I think this mean that apple should care about simulator settings, based on the orientation when simulator start including plist options.